# How to call a constructor from a different class

Tags: java, junit, constructor, call, subclass

The constructor `MappaFermi()` sets the attribute `mappaName` of the class `Mappa()` and the attribute `settoreNome` of the class `Settore()`

```
public class Settore {
        private Nome settoreNome;
        private char letteraX;
        private final int coordinataX;
        private final int coordinataY;

    public Settore (int coordinataX, int coordinataY){
        this.coordinataX=coordinataX;
        this.coordinataY=coordinataY;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return coordinataX;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return coordinataY;
    }
    public Nome getSettoreNome() {
        return settoreNome;
    }
    public void setSettoreNome(Nome settoreNome) {
        this.settoreNome = settoreNome;
    }

}
```

.

```
public enum Nome {
    SICURO, PERICOLOSO, SCIALUPPA, ALIENI, UMANI
}
```

.

```
public class Mappa {
    private Name mappaName;
    private final Settore [][] settore;
    private int Matrice [][];
    private static final int X=23;
    private static final int Y=14;

    public Mappa (){
        settore = new Settore[X][Y];
        for (int i=0; i < X; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<Y; j++) {
                settore[i][j] = new Settore (i,j);
            }
        }
    }

    public Name getMappaName() {
        return mappaName;
    }

    public void setMappaName(Name mappaName) {
        this.mappaName = mappaName;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class MappaFermi extends Mappa {

    public MappaFermi() {
        setMappaName(Name.FERMI);

        new Alieni(10,8);//This creates a new Object Settore with coordinataX= 10, coordinataY=8 and settoreNome=Nome.ALIENI
        new Umani(10,9);

    }
 }
```

I'm doing a JUnit test to verify that the value of the attribute `settoreNome` of the `Settore`(10,8) is indeed Alieni when I run the constructor `MappaFermi`(). I don't know how exactly I should run the method `getSettoreNome`() from it.

```
public class MappaFermiTest {
    @Test
    public void testSettoreAlieni(){
        Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi();
        Settore settore = //When I run MappaFermi() it runs new Alieni(10,8) so i want to get Settore(10,8) using Settore settore so i can get the settoreNome using getSettoreNome()
        assertEquals(Nome.ALIENI, settore.getSettoreNome());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in MappaFermi constructor you should call Mappa constructor (e.g., `super()`), then using Mappa property `settore` go ahead and assign them to the coordinates you want: `settore[10][8] = new Alieni(10,8)`.

Comment: Which Settore's name do you want to get?

Comment: i don't see how changing the assignation makes me get the settore(10,8)

Comment: in MappaFermi() when i run new Alieni(10,8); it creates an object Settore with coordinataX=10, coordinataY=8 and settoreNome=Nome.ALIENI, so i want to call that object because if i write newSettore(10,8) it's gonna create another object with the same coordinataX and coordinataY but with the settoreNome null